# ansible: create temporary inventory with multiple groups with add_host or group_by

Tags: ansible

Is there any way to create an in memory inventory during provisioning tasks  with add_host or group_by modules such:

```
[SET]
1.1.1.1
[SET:vars]

ip_address={{ inventory_hostname }}

[SET1]
1.1.1.2
[SET:vars]
ip_address={{ inventory_hostname }}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "provisioning tasks"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html).  You can do something like this (if you provide more information in your question, we can provide more specificity ourselves):

```
- add_host:
    hostname: 1.1.1.1
    groups: SET
- add_host:
    hostname: 1.1.1.2
    groups: SET1
```

This will dynamically add 1.1.1.1 to the inventory as part of the `SET` group and 1.1.1.2 to the inventory as part of the `SET1` group.  there are a couple of good example of doing this during provision steps for [rackspace](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_rax.html)

tasks:

```
  - name: Provision a set of instances
    local_action:
        module: rax
        name: "{{ rax_name }}"
        flavor: "{{ rax_flavor }}"
        image: "{{ rax_image }}"
        count: "{{ rax_count }}"
        group: "{{ group }}"
        wait: yes
    register: rax
  - name: Add the instances we created (by public IP) to the group 'raxhosts'
    local_action:
        module: add_host
        hostname: "{{ item.name }}"
        ansible_host: "{{ item.rax_accessipv4 }}"
        ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ item.rax_adminpass }}"
        groups: raxhosts
    with_items: "{{ rax.success }}"
    when: rax.action == 'create'
```