# Ansible inventory: Defining group affiliation with host variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am designing an inventory structure to be used for hosts across the world.
They come in groups (several types of hosts (devices, not just PC\mac) per location) and differ in numerous characteristics which affect how they are to be managed (effectively - what role they will be given). This means there are inherently many groups and it is common for a host to be a member of several.

Also, this inventory is prone to changes (due to new deployment, movement or re-purposing of a given host).
Due to the above I want group membership to be defined on the host side and also automate the process as much as possible.

I read about add_host and group_by but unsure:

1. If I understand the usage correctly (for example, unsure if I can use group_by with regular host variables)
2. How to best utilize them (if there is a best practice or common considerations which I'm missing - cannot find a comprehensive example)

Following is a sample of properties (not real, obvs):

```
group_vars/host001:
type: "PC"
os: "windows"
os_version: "10"
has_widescreen: True
office_version: "2019"
<more properties>

group_vars/host041:
type: "mac"
os: "macos"
macos_version: "10.13"
<more properties>

group_vars/host053:
type: "mac"
os: "macos"
os_version: "10.13"
office_version: "2007"
<more properties>
```

Then to create the groups I want to use, for example:

```
# create groups named "windows 10" and "macos 10.13", under the groups "windows" and "macos" accordingly.
- group_by:
    key: {{ os }}-{{ os_version }}
    parents:
      - {{ os }} 

# create groups named "office2007" and office2019"
- group_by:
    key: {{ office_version }}

# create group of hosts with wide screens
add_host: hostname={{ item }} groups=has_widescreen
  with_items: groups['all']
  when: (has_widescreen == True)
```

Is this valid usage? Is it recommended? Is there somewhere a comprehensive example of dynamic grouping with many groups which one can learn from?

Comment: Some preemptive notes:
1. Sorry if this is too many Qs in one post, I thought of breaking this up but it seemed they wouldn't make sense separately.
2. While there are 2 Qs with seemingly relevant titles (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289477, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202452), neither specifically address the issue of using variables to define group affiliation.

Comment: You are defining vars in your inventory (`type`, `os`, `os_version`) that you can get directly or infer from the host facts (`ansible_distribution`, `ansible_distribution_release`, `ansible_distribution_version`, `ansible_distribuion_major_version`, ...). Moreover, if you want to control `group_by` from vars you can set directly from the host, have a look at [local facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d)

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator, I am aware that os and os_version can be obtained as facts but was not familiar with local facts as a work around for defining facts. Still I'd prefer to avoid having to "plant" files in my hosts. Are you saying that my intended use of variables is not possible and group_by can only be used with facts?

Comment: I'm not saying anything else than what is my comment above: there are facts you can discover to get your OS and you can if needed set custom facts directly on your host. For the rest of your question, did you try ? Didn't it work as expected ? What is the exact problem you're having when creating those dynamically ?

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator, I was indeed having trouble setting up a sandbox to test this and also with syntax (missing quotations, etc.).
The phrasing of your initial response made me question my approach here and I figured out that I need less groups and a better use of variables.
Solved this part with a simple 2 level group by (similar to the first example that I give).
I appreciate your guidance.